# CSS simulate element move

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I have a site with two sidebars and the content in the middle. In the HTML it's positioned as:

```
sidebar 1 - floated left
middle content - floated left
sidebar 2 - floated right
```

And that's also how it looks on the site. All good. The problem is i'm trying to make the site responsive, and i want the content to be at the top and the sidebars to jump down below, and i'm not entirely sure how to do that. I could use javascript, but i would much prefer CSS to do it, if possible.

Here's the site i'm working on if it helps:

[URL no longer allowed]

Squeeze the window down a bit and watch the left sidebar appear above the content - not good.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your divs so the body content div is first.
Then wrap the first sidebar and body content in a div floating the body content to the right. Use a media query so that once your down to mobile size you set the floats to none

```
<div float:left>
  <main-content float:right>
  <sidebar float:left>
<\div>
<sidebar float:right>
```